# jQuery find next element with class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a quite simple question, that ate me 4 hours and is not yet solved: How to find next span with specific class with jQuery?
I have the following html

```
<tr>
    <td align="right">Име:&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left">
         <input type="text" value="<?=$profileSQL['user_name']; ?>" name="user_name" class="input required" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right" colspan="2">
         <span class="error"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and I validate it with jQuery.
I want if there's an error message, generated with js (just a string), jQuery to find nearest span with class `.error` and to `text()` the message in there. I tried with `nextAll()`, `next("span.error")` and a lot of other things, but nothing helped me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try showing the actual rendered html as seen by the browser (view source) rather than the, I *assume,* php.

Comment: @DavidThomas: this php is just a string, but i tried your way and the result is the same
@jAndy: By root node I think you mean the main container? It's table, if you're asking that

Comment: How do you detect the error?  What is the element (*this*) that you are starting from?  What does your javascript currently look like?

Comment: `function validate() {
 var err = 0;
 $("#profileForm").find(".required").each(function(){
  var elem = $(this);
  if(elem.attr("name") == "user_name")
  {
   if(!elem.val())
   {
    err++;
    elem.addClass("errorInput");
    elem.next(".error").text(nameErrEmptyMsg);
   } else if(elem.val().length < 5) {
    err++;
    elem.addClass("errorInput");
    elem.next(".error").text(nameErrShortMsg);
   }
  } else {
   
  }
 });
 if(err > 0)
 {
  return false;
 }
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this may not be exactly what you're looking for, but if you've GOT the input, like this:

```
var input = $('input[name="user_name"]');
```

Then you can just do:

```
input.parents('tr').eq(0).next().find('.error').text(nameErrEmptyMsg);
```

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that .next() and .nextAll() only search through through the siblings (elements that have the same parent).

From jQuery documentation:

> Description: Get all following
>   siblings of each element in the set of
>   matched elements, optionally filtered
>   by a selector.

In your case you have:

```
  <tr> 
     <td> title here</td> 
     <td><input name="user_name"/> </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td colspan="2">
       <span class="error"></span>
     </td> 
   </tr>
```

As i understand your JQuery code is run on the input, right? In this case before calling newxt() or nextAll() you should first go up 2 levels, until the  and afterwards select the next  because there is the  that you want to find, so:

here's a working example to check it:
http://jsfiddle.net/EM5Gw/

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  console.log($("td>span").next().find(".error").text())
```

Comment: I use only IE (other browsers are forbidden with php), so I got no Firebug

Comment: Hi, regarding FIREBUG and IE, you can get FIREBUG-LITE that will work with IE6+. See `http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `next('span.error')`:

http://jsfiddle.net/wPZgg/

Comment: have you taken a look at the jsfiddle? isn't that what you want it to do? also, what jquery version are you using?

Comment: Update the Fiddle JamesHalsall by adding your tr's inside a table which is inside a div so it will actually render.  Then you will find that your code does not work.